Data not reaching to backend
I have a web app with React as the frontend and Express as the backend for RESTful APIs. Users can log in using either email/password or Facebook.
When users log in with Facebook, their data does not reach the backend to update(but with the login their email, name saves to the database). However, when testing with Postman, the backend updates data correctly.
How can I ensure that the backend receives and updates data correctly when users log in with Facebook?

I tried using PUT method
I tried passing sample data
I tried creating separate databases for facebook users
But none of them worked. I'm using passport js for facebook login.

here i have attached a code segment for facebook login
passport.use(
  new FacebookStrategy(
    {
      clientID: 'CLIENT_ID',
      clientSecret: 'CLIENT_SECRET',
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:5003/facebook/callback',
      profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'name', 'gender', 'picture.type(large)', 'email'],
    },
    async function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      try {
        let user = await FacebookUser.findOne({ where: { id: profile.id } });

        if (user) {
          console.log('User found!', user.id);
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          const newUser = await FacebookUser.create({
            id: profile.id,
            name: profile.name.familyName,
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            picture: profile.photos[0].value,
          });

          await fbCoins.create({
            facebookId: newUser.id,
            coins: 100,
          });

          console.log('User and Coins entry created successfully');
          return done(null, newUser);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error during Facebook authentication:', err);
        return done(err);
      }
    }
  )
);

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }));

app.get(
  '/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: '/failed',
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    var userId = req.user.dataValues.id;
    res.redirect('http://localhost:5173/home?fb_user_id=' + userId);
  }
);

app.get('/home', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user.id);
  res.render('profile', { user: req.user });
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/');
}

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  FacebookUser.findByPk(id, function (err, user) {
    return done(err, user);
  });
});


@DarkBee I have updated the question with the code, and there's no error message but it shows in network tab in browser, time for the request is pending!

try using the below for the method and check it by using the Postman API
if (user) {
  console.log('User found!', user.id);
  // Update user data if needed
  user.name = profile.name.familyName;
  user.email = profile.emails[0].value;
  user.picture = profile.photos[0].value;
  await user.save();
  return done(null, user);
}

